# How To Control Scale Numbers in Decimal in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, numbers, decimal, scale

Is there any function in Sql Server 2008 that controls scale numbers.For example
if we have a decimal number 123.456 and  in function if pass 0 it should return 123, if i pass 1 then should return 123.4 if pass 2 then return 123.45 and if pass 3 then return 123.456.If there is no inbult function then Please let me know any user define function.Thanks, Ravi

Comment: Are you sure you want truncation, not rounding?

Comment: A function like this requires a return datatype, which in your case would differ based on the argument you're passing in. You can just use CONVERT(NUMERIC(x,y),col) WHERE y is the number of decimals.

Comment: No, Rounding is also OK. I have no problem with that.

Comment: Cairnz - That was also my first thought, problem is that you can't use a variable to replace y. I managed to make a simple function to solved this problem.

Comment: I surgest you use Alex K's solution instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_test (
@a INT,
@b FLOAT
) RETURNS DECIMAL(12,6)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN CAST(@b * POWER(10, @a) AS INT)*1.0 / POWER(10, @a)
END

SELECT dbo.f_test(2, 123.456) AS RESULT

RESULT
----------
123.450000
```

Answer (score 2):

`ROUND()` can truncate;

```
select round(123.456, 3, 1) union
select round(123.456, 2, 1) union
select round(123.456, 1, 1) union
select round(123.456, 0, 1) 

>>123.456
>>123.450
>>123.400
>>123.000
```

If you don't want the trailing zeros remove them in the presentation layer, cast to a varchar or `cast(round(123.456, 3, 1) as float)`